# Why does World of Goo on the iOS have to be downloaded via wifi?

Tags: ios, world-of-goo

Why does World of Goo on the iOS have to be downloaded via wifi?

I can't add much more to that...

On the app page it's got:

Must be downloaded with wifi connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to using a 3G/4G connection. The reason is specified in the previous sentence: **This is a big game...**

You can of course download it on your iTunes on your computer first, then sync it to your iOS via the cable. The developers just didn't spell this out for ya (which they should have).

Note: I have downloaded much bigger games like Mass Effect: Infiltrator, which is more than 1G. You can install it via either Wi-Fi or iTunes on your PC/Mac. This is definitely not a game you want to download via 3G/4G.

Comment: Oh ok, i do find it strange that they left out about the 3G/4G, as it makes a lot more sense!

Comment: Agreed. A very ambiguous statement, which raises more questions than it addresses....

Comment: Are you even allowed to download files bigger than "x" mb/gb set amount when on 3G/4G?

Comment: Depending on where you live.

Comment: oh ok, i'm in NZ, and i believe its capped at 100mb download (least for 3G)

Comment: I use Vodafone (yes I am in NZ too) and I have 3Gb a month.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3446/discussion-between-gareth-jones-and-james-jiao)

Answer (score 3):

**Apple** sets size cap for downloading apps by 3G. Last [update from **March 2012**](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2012/03/you-can-now-download-ios-apps-up-to-50mb-over-3g/) make it possible to download app under 50MB.

**World of Goo** like other big iOS games are far far over this limit so they must be downloaded by WiFi or transfered from your iTunes.